# What is the best way to work with plenty z-index parameters?

Tags: html, css, z-index

My project is totally messed up now, because I am using so many z-indexes.
Now I am unable to understand why some classes are hiding and there is no way for me to resolve it. Is there anything I can do to resolve these issues? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Go through your Z-Indexes and change them one at a time. Generally people tend to use big numbers so they remember which is which. For example, Increase your z indexes by 100 each time, or reduce them by 100 each time, or even 1000.

Your question will probably get downvoted haha. Sorry bro hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a preprocessor like Sass/SCSS (or Less or Stylus), you can use variables to keep track of your z-indexes. In sass, for example, you can do something like this:

```
$z: (
  base: 1,
  menus: 10,
  modals: 100
)

.modal { z-index: map-get($z, modals); }
.some-other-modal-thing { z-index: map-get($z, modals); }
```

That'll help going forward; for now, you'll have to clean it up manually. Search+replace in your text editor of choice should help you track down and update any references. It may be helpful to go through the instances of `z-index` one by one, removing one at a time and seeing what breaks. (If nothing breaks, kill the rule and move on to the next instance!)

Answer (score 0):

Compartmentalize things.

Build high level layers with high level components. I.e. If you have a menubar, a sidebar, and the main section, you only need to layer three things. Then worry about what's inside these later.

If you're trying to layer each individual thing one by one with all the other individual things on the page, you're doing it wrong.

In other words, use common sense and do what people do in all other aspects of life: don't just make one long list of things, but rather put those things in groups that are way easier to handle and understand.

Technically, relative and absolute positioning create a new z-indexing context. Fixed positioning does that as well depending on the browser, Firefox changed the handling of this in some version and Chrome handles it differently to be consistent with mobile browsers, if I'm not mistaken, but somebody would need to confirm that.